# Como utilizar os métodos setX() e setY() da biblioteca FPDF.

Tags: php, fpdf

Já pesquisei na internet mas não obtive esclarecimento sobre o tema, gostaria de saber se alguém poderia demonstrar um procedimento de utilização destes métodos.

Estou criando um cabeçalho com a biblioteca [`fpdf`](http://www.fpdf.org/) e preciso utilizar os métodos `setX` e `setY` para ajustar meu conteúdo, porém não sei como fazer isso. Como utilizar estas funções corretamente?

Comment: Já olhou a documentação? [**setY**](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/sety.htm) e [**setX**](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setx.htm).

Comment: sim, mas não compreendi!

Comment: Mas para que você acha que o `setX` e `setY` irão lhe servir?

Comment: Seria para desenha um retangulo?

Comment: Então, preciso  criar um cabeçalho usando o setX e setY, pois ele terá imagens e varias tabelas.

Comment: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/index.php

Comment: coloca setx(30);
e depois poem algum texto com o cell, vc vai ver o texto, o lugar em que o texto começar é a posição x que vc definiu com o 30

Answer (score 1):

Isso serve para definir o posicionamento do elemento que você irá fazer a saída, funciona como um ponteiro, a cada "set" ele coloca seu ponteiro na posição desejada:

```
//posiciona verticalmente 
$pdf->SetY("20"); 

//posiciona horizontalmente 
$pdf->SetX("10");
```

Você pode definir também:

```
//define as fontes atraves da pasta font 
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','font/'); 
/* instancia a classe FPDF passando a Orientação da página,
   medida e Tipo de Folha; */ 
$pdf = new FPDF("P","mm","A5"); 

//fonte do documento
$pdf->SetFont('arial','',10); 

//posição na vertical no caso -2 seria o limite da margem 
$pdf->SetY("-2"); 

//::::::::::::::::::Cabecalho:::::::::::::::::::: 
//escreve o titulo.... 
//largura = 0 
//altura = 5 
//texto
//borda = 0 
//quebra de linha = 0 
//alinhamento = L (esqueda) 
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'titulo blábláblá',0,0,'L'); 

//escreve um subtítulo... 
//largura = 0 
//altura = 5
//texto 
//borda = 0 
//quebra de linha = 1 
// alinhamento = R (direita) 
$pdf->Cell(0,5,'subtítulo blábláblá',0,1,'R'); 

//escreve uma linha qualquer... 
//largura = 0 
//altura = 0 
//texto
//borda = 1 
//quebra de linha = 1 
// alinhamento = L (esqueda) 
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1,1,'L'); 

//quebra de linha 
$pdf->Ln(8); 

//::::::::::::::::::Define o conteúdo de texto::::::::::::::::::::: 
//tamanho de fonte e tipo 
$pdf->SetFont('times','',8); 

//posiciona verticalmente o texto 
$pdf->SetY("20"); 

//posiciona horizontalmente e horizontalmente
$pdf->SetX("10"); 

//escreve o conteudo de texto 
$texto="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Morbi commodo ut erat vitae ultrices. Sed urna nisi, sodales sed lorem vel, dictum euismod orci. 

Donec viverra vulputate leo, a laoreet erat posuere ac. Quisque vel leo neque. Aliquam in diam semper nibh mattis pellentesque. 

Donec nulla nibh, ornare sit amet lorem nec, ornare consequat est. Mauris molestie lorem eget euismod tristique. 

" ;
//escreve a saída do texto
$pdf->Write(5, $texto); 

//::::::::::::::::::definindo o rodapé da página:::::::::::::::::::::: 
//posiciona verticalmente 
$pdf->SetY("185"); 

//define a fonte do rodapé
$pdf->SetFont('arial','',8); 
//se quiser colocar uma data no rodapé... 
$data = date("d/m/Y"); 
$formtData="criado em ".$data; 
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1,1,'L'); 
$pdf->Cell(0,4,'São Paulo - SP',0,1,'R'); 
//faz a saída da data
$pdf->Cell(0,4,$formtData,0,0,'R');

//executa a criação do arquivo
$pdf->Output("helloworld.pdf", "I"); //S (salvar) ou I (imprimir)
```

Answer (score 0):

Então, pode ser de ajuda alguém!
A utilização é:

```
$var->setX(valor eixo x);
$var->Cell();

$var->setY(valor eixo y);
$var->Cell();

$var->setXY(eixo x, eixo y);
$var->Cell();
```

Comment: Isso não explica muita coisa poderia detalhar a resposta ?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, então de acordo com o comentário acima

Digamos que você defina esses parâmetros

```
// Definir o SetX
$pdf->SetX("20");
// Definir o SetY
$pdf->SetY("30");
```

Todos os elementos que você criar abaixo estarão nessa localização. Para definir lugares diferentes para cada elemento, você deve sempre definir outro X, Y antes

Por exemplo:

```
$pdf->SetX("20"); // Aqui eu estou definindo o X da primeira célula
$pdf->SetY("30"); // Aqui eu estou definindo o X da primeira célula
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1,1,'L'); // Aqui eu estou criando a primeira célula

// Agora eu quero outra célula em outra posição, é só eu definir o X, Y novamente
$pdf->SetX("10"); // Aqui eu estou definindo o X da segunda célula
$pdf->SetY("5"); // Aqui eu estou definindo o X da segunda célula
$pdf->Cell(0,0,'',1,1,'L'); // Aqui eu estou criando a segunda célula
```

E assim segue até terminar a quantidade de célular que você quer