# FPDF Problemas no posicionamento SetY()

Tags: php, fpdf

Recentemente estive utilizando a classe do PHP Fpdf para gerar meu relatório, porém tenho o seguinte problema:

Como faço para posicionar uma imagem que está la na ultima página do relatório para a primeira? (quero não escrever a imagem antes do resto do código, mas sim reposiciona-la até que ela suba para a primeira página).

PS:Tentei utilizar o SetY() com um valor negativo a imagem até sobe, mas ela so sobe dentro da atual página onde ela está e não até chegar na primeira página.

Agradeço desde já, estou com esse problema ja faz alguns dias e não consigo resolver.

Comment: Olha esse resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50203/como-utilizar-os-m%C3%A9todos-setx-e-sety-da-biblioteca-fpdf/81082#81082

Comment: Eu verifiquei, mas esse método ele desloca textos para cima se usar um valor negativo, até ai tudo bem, mas ele tem um limite, caso eu tenha um texto lá na ultima página, ele só subirá até o limite da atual página que ele está e não até a primeira página do documento.